# CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'var

Tags: .net, dll, reference, .net-assembly, .net-framework-version

My web application was working perfectly. There was no issue with that.

Suddenly I was need to add a reference of System.Web.Helpers.ddl in my project. After adding this in my project I am getting an error

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'var' on this line var date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(i);

before this it was working perfectly, I didn't made any change in my code.

```
protected void Bind_Year()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(int));
        for (int i = -2; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(i);
            var year = date.Year;
            dt.Rows.Add(year);

        }
        DropDownList3.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownList3.DataBind();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WebMsgBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Which .NET version or C# version is this?

Comment: right now the .net framework is 4.0

Comment: Have you perhaps defined a type somewhere that is named `var`?

Comment: And that is the real code, not a retype of more code, ie. you copied and pasted it here, you did not change it?

Comment: nah, I didn't change anything except adding System.Web.Helpers reference to my solution. Before that it was working fine

Comment: No, what I mean is, the code in the question, that is copied directly from your program. You didn't change it on the way before posting the question, perhaps to "simplify" it?

Comment: yes, i copied it direct from my program. I didn't change it before posting. by the way why I should change it?

Comment: And that is the exact error message?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a type named `var` somewhere, try placing the cursor on it and hitting F12 in Visual Studio and see what happens.

Comment: It shows a class names var.cs. I need to delete this class?

Comment: I can't tell you what to do with it, but naming it `var` is a bad idea. You should know what is in that class and whether it is safe to delete. At the very least I would change its name, naming a type or member the same as a C# word is a bad idea, as you've discovered.

Comment: Tonzz of thanks Mr. Lasse V. Karlsen. I dont know from where this class came. And also there is nothing in this class except namespaces. I deleted that classs, now it is working fine as it was working before the adding reference. Thanks a LOT :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you got a type somewhere named `var`.

I didn't think this was possible myself, so I tried it in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

```
void Main()
{
    var x = DateTime.Today;
}
public class var
{
}
```

Sure enough, it gives me this compiler error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'UserQuery.var'

So apparently you must have such a class in your project, or in a referenced assembly.

Naming types or members the same as built-in keywords is a bad idea.

To fix this you should rename your type to something else. Unless the world you're modelling have a concept called "var", I'd say a more descriptive name is probably better anyway, but if you really want the name, consider just uppercasing the V making it `Var` and the compiler should stop complaining.

Comment: Sir, Sorry but I didn't add this class, even I don't know from where it automatically came in my APP_Code folder.

Comment: *I didn't think this was possible myself :* It is possible because `var` is not a reserved word, [it is a contextual keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx). Any contextual keywords can be used as identifiers whereas reserved keywords are not. And.. +1 :)